# Flink with Kafka Consumer doesn't work

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to benchmark Spark vs Flink, for this purpose I am making several tests. However Flink doesn't work with Kafka, meanwhile with Spark works perfect.

The code is very simple:

```
val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

val properties = new Properties()
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
properties.setProperty("group.id", "myGroup")
println("topic: "+args(0))
val stream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09[String](args(0), new SimpleStringSchema(), properties))
stream.print

env.execute()
```

I use kafka 0.9.0.0 with the same topics (in consumer[Flink] and producer[Kafka console]), but when I send my jar to the cluster, nothing happens:

[Cluster Flink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm1i1.png)

What it could be happening?

Comment: Are you reading from a pre-filled Kafka topic (to have identical input for Flink and Spark) or simultaneously writing data to and reading data from Kafka?

Comment: I send data over the producer at the same time that Flink is up

Comment: Have you tried the FlinkKafkaConsumer082 connector and/or specifying the zookeeper.connect property as shown here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446374/can-anyone-share-a-flink-kafka-example-in-scala)? While the docs say the zookeeper.connect property is not required for the FlinkKafkaConsumer09 connector, it may be a good experiment. If yes, does the flink job stay running? Where are you looking for the output?

Comment: I tried with the connector of my version (0.9), although I tested with both options (with and without zookeeper.connect) and it didn't fix :(

Answer (score 2):

Your stream.print will not print in console on flink .It will write to flink0.9/logs/recentlog. Other-wise you can add your own logger  for confirming output.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case (a Source chained into a Sink) the Webinterface will never report Bytes/Records sent/received. Note that this will change in the somewhat near future.

Please check whether the job-/taskmanager logs do not contain any output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however in console either nothing happens

Comment: I think in this case the `taskmanager*.out` files will contain the output. It should be easier to test this if you also write your results to a Kafka topic from both Flink and Spark.

Comment: I have this in the log:

- Consumer is going to read the following topics (with number of partitions): wordCount3 (1)

And then:

- Disconnect from JobManager null
- Received job kafka stream.
- Could not submit job kafka stream, because there is no connection to a JobManager.