# Flink can't connect with Kafka on the cluster server

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm trying to benchmark Spark vs Kafka with Flink. When I run the test code locally, everything works fine. But when I run the same exact code on the Flink cluster server (EMR), it just says "Starting Execution". Log shows Kafka has never been connected. Anyone knows why?

My code and problem is basically the same as what's in this post: [Flink with Kafka Consumer doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841342/flink-with-kafka-consumer-doesnt-work)

Comment: Can you show us a little sample of your code ?

Comment: It's not clear where Kafka is running or how you've configured the network connections to allow for "non local" connections, but setting "localhost:9092" from EMR won't work

Comment: I figured it out. The underlying fact was that everything actually worked fine and the result got printed at Std.out instead of the console.