# Flink Kafka cannot find org/I0Itec/zkclient/serialize/ZkSerializer

Tags: scala, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka, apache-flink

Here is my simple Scala program to use Kafka in Flink:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{ProducerConfig, KafkaProducer, ProducerRecord} 
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment._ 
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka 
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.api._ 
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization._ 
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo._ 

object TestKafka { 
  def main(args: Array[String]) { 
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment 
    val stream = env 
      .addSource(new KafkaSource[String]("localhost:2181", "test", new SimpleStringSchema)) 
      .addSink(new KafkaSink[String]("localhost:2181", "test", new JavaDefaultStringSchema)) 

    env.execute("Test Kafka") 
  } 
}
```

in build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.flink" % "flink-scala" % "0.9.0", "org.apache.flink" % "flink-clients" % "0.9.0") 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.8.2.1" 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-streaming-scala" % "0.9.0" 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-connector-kafka" % "0.9.0" exclude("org.apache.kafka", "kafka_${scala.binary.version}") 
libraryDependencies += "com.101tec" % "zkclient" % "0.5"
```

I'm using "sbt assembly" to build a fat jar, so the target jar file is supposed to contain everything. However, there are errors when running the target jar file:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/I0Itec/zkclient/serialize/ZkSerializer 
        at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:66) 
        at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:69) 
        at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.createJavaConsumerConnector(ConsumerConnector.scala:105) 
        at kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(ConsumerConnector.scala) 
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.api.KafkaSource.initializeConnection(KafkaSource.java:175) 
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.api.KafkaSource.open(KafkaSource.java:207) 
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:33) 
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:56) 
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openOperator(StreamTask.java:158) 
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.invoke(SourceStreamTask.java:52) 
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:559) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.I0Itec.zkclient.serialize.ZkSerializer 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) 
.........
```

I already put zkclient-0.5.jar under /lib. Anyone can shed some light?

Comment: Did you double check, that ZkSerializer is contained in the fat-jar or zkclient-0.5.jar?

Comment: "grep ZkSerializer" in the generated fat jar file shows it exists. I also put zkclient-0.5.jar under $FLINK_HOME/lib/, which contains the class of ZkSerializer.

Comment: Did you try using version zkclient 0.3 (this is the version that is included in Flink dependencies)? You are using version 0.5.

Comment: Tried copying zkclient-0.3.jar to $FLINK_HOME/lib and also updated build.sbt. However, I still get the same error: **flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.api.KafkaSource.open** failed; NoClassDefFoundError: ZkSerializer.  I cannot think of any reason.

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe you should ask at user@flink.apache.org

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Flink's KafkaSource in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419408/how-to-use-flinks-kafkasource-in-scala)